# How to optimize 2 dimensional matrix reading speed?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, matrix

I'm working on a 2D game. I have the game map saved on a js object {} called gameMap. My problem is that reading an item on the matrix takes too long. For collision detection I usually have to check 10 or 20 items of the map matrix which takes around 1ms and having 10 characters on screen collision detection becomes the bottleneck of the app, taking 10ms of the 16ms each frame should last. Also when the map gets too big times scale up.

Let's say Map has 1000 x 1000 items. Right now if I want to check what is at position `(-100,200)` I check `gameMap['-100'][200]`. My idea is to divide the map in quadrants that would group 100 x 100 items. So to check `(-100,200)` I would test `gameMap[quadrantName][-100][200]`. This would mean that while gameMap would be about the same size it would work with a lot less items, and probably read speed would scale up in a far smaller proportion. Does anyone know if this would make reading faster? What else can I do to improve reading speed?

Comment: relevant search: `game collision detection`

Comment: If you know how to do it, you can just test using jsperf :)

Comment: I really thought that array lookup times did not depend much on array size... It seems like gameMap is an object {} and not an array [], you should make it an array and access it with integer values, not strings. If you need indexes -100 to 100 just add 100 to it and make it 0-200.

Comment: Also be careful that the arrays are correctly initialized with 0s and of full length, at startup. Don't go adding values to shorter arrays inside loops... just in case.

Comment: I'm using an object and not an array. I read somewhere than on js both arrays [] and ovjects {} have the same lookup times. Maybe I misunderstood it. Will an array be read faster?  Can manage without negative indexes but It's easier having them

Comment: Would using a quadtree improve a lot the reading speed? I found some open source implementations but the map is huge and I constantly have to loop through areas, would that be possible using a quadtree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a 10000x10000 array of bytes will consume 100MB! Do you really need such a large array. Perhaps you'd be better of storing just the coordinates of all your elements...

As to your question - you could convert your 2d array to a **1d array** and access all cells via

```
gameMap[y * 10000 + x]
```

where 10000 would be the 'width' of your map. So there would be no need to divide the map into quadrants.

Comment: I exagerated with the size, the map is autogenerated as you explore it but you can quickly get it to be 1000x2000. The object is not an array but a regular object {}, since I need it to hold negative values. It seems like a good idea. Would this really speed up reading speed?

Comment: I was thinking this is completely opposite of my theory. Will increasing the number of items really be faster? I thought that making it deeper would mean it would work with fewer items on each layer making reading faster

Comment: If you acccess the array at e.g. index 999, there is no loop that runs trough all the positions from 0 to 999 but the processor simply accesses that position in memory. As for negative values, simply add an offset so your smallest values are 0. E.g. if you have a field from -500 to 500, just add an offset of 500.